# IMU MPU9250 Magnetometer data Question

Tags: pi-4, sensor

I am working on implementing compass using IMU magnetometer using https://www.adafruit.com/product/4554. While calibrating magnetometer with its offset and scaling factor, it works well right after I calibrate data. However, after some time pass by, I try to measure the angle again. However, eventhough the direction was same, it gives another value that is about 40 degree off from previous measurement. I know magnetometer is easily affected by iron and surrounding environment. But, I was testing in same place with same set up. I tried to saerch the internet, however, I do not seem to be find one. Anyone has know about this issue? I am kind of wondering that this issue is caused because it is cheap sensor? Because even iPhone compass is not giving steady heading value everytime eventhough facing same direction.

Thank you!

Comment: This site is for questions related to the Raspberry Pi.